# Doing C tutorials on the iMac, stuck on a challenge

Tags: c, terminal, math.h

I'm doing C programming on Xcode, Apple's IDE for the Mac and following the Big Nerd Ranch's guide to Objective C programming book. One of the challenge questions is to use the  library in C to display the sine of 1 radian. I imported math.h and did

double sin = sin(3.14);

but it's giving me an error.

Comment: What error is it giving you? It is important to always include such information when asking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Ummm....`3.14 != 1`. Also, we cannot view your monitor, and therefore **cannot see the error message that you're getting.**

Comment: An upvote? Seriously? Why?!

Answer (score 3):

1 radian is not pi, it is 1.

You can't use a variable name that is a function name.

You want

```
double myValue = sin(1.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't name the variable the same name as the function.

Try

```
double s = sin(3.14);
```